# Why do I need to add index 1 to my childNodes array, when I want to get the first child?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a function in javascript which should output a text entered into an input field.
My code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate()
    {
        var input = document.body.childNodes[1];
        document.write(input.value);
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="calculate()"/>
</body>
```

Now what I don´t understand is why do I have to put the index "1" into my childNodes array? Logically it should be "0" since `<input type="text"/>` is the first child of body.

Comment: What browser, they handle whitespace nodes differently?

Comment: If you're running Firefox w/Firebug or Chrome, you can look at your console by pressing F12. If you type in `document.body.childNodes` you'll be able to see what all the nodes are and what the first element will be.

Comment: AND you should never use `document.write`to debug anymore, use `console.log`.

Comment: I am using Firefox and Firebug tells me that the first and third node is: <TextNode textContent="\n"> which means Firefox counts whitespace as well. Is there a way to tell my javascript to ignore whitespace?

Comment: Use `.children[0]`. The `.children` property gives only elements, and nothing else *(except that older IE will also give comment nodes if there are any)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM spec mandates that whitespace betwwen nodes in your HTML, should be presend in the childNodes list, as text nodes. So with HTML like

```
<div id="parent"><div>child 1</div> abc <div>child2</div></div>  </div>
```

we would expect the childnodes for the parent div to be

1. The first child div
2. A text node between the two child divs, containing the text " abc "
3. The second child div
4. A whitespace text node after the second child div, containing "  "

If you want to get only element nodes instead of text nodes, either check the nodeType property of the childnodes when going through the loop (its 1 for elements and 3 for text nodes, IIRC) or use the "children" array instead of "childNodes".

Note that older browsers might not implement the children array and that Internet Explorer might not show whitespace nodes when iterating through childNodes.

Answer (score 0):

No, the first child is a text-node in some browsers with white-space only. But you could use [`Element.firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.firstElementChild)